# rss-parer: this.removeAllListeners is not a function error

Tags: reactjs, parsing, rss, javascript-objects, react-library

i'm trying to integrate news feeds into a website, rss-parser is the library am using for parsing and the website is built with ReactJs. i keeping getting "this.removeAllListeners is not a function" error message. [error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghrnv.png). this is my code [my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hr63m.png)

expecting it to parse all newsfeeds from the url and convert to javascroipt object

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.